# Fourier transform doubting factorization

Tags: fourier-analysis, factoring

I have to find the fourier transform for 
$$
{1\over 1+16t^4}
$$
I guess going there is a better way to solve it than going throug the integral but I'm not even sure if the factorization i made is correct
$$
1+16t^4=(1+4t^2)^2-8t^2=(4t^2+\sqrt 8t+1)(4t^2-\sqrt 8t+1)
$$
Then i find the two couple of complex conjugates as solutions, but they are really ugly how do i find the transform from the factors at this point? 
Maybe I'm approaching this problem the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your factorization is correct and leads in the next step to the correct roots. Their expression is not that horrible.

In another choice of the first factorization, You get from $16t^4=-1$ the reduced equations $4t^2=\pm i$ and from there $2t=(\pm1\pm i)/\sqrt2$ where the sign choices are independent..

You can evaluate the Fourier integrals via residual calculus.